# Remove shortcut and associated file with Innosetup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, delete-file, startmenu

As part of an application update, I want to remove an old start menu entry if it exists, and the file it points to.  I tried:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{group}\User's Manual (PDF)"
Type: files; Name: "{app}\User's Manual.pdf"
```

The actual file itself got deleted, but not the start menu entry.  Also - neither operation was recorded in the install log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shortcuts have an extension, try:

```
Type: files; Name: "{group}\User's Manual (PDF).lnk"
```

Comment: That worked, thanks very much.  You would think they would follow the syntax of the [Icons] entry, which doesn't need the ".lnk".

Comment: @rossmcm - Yeah, only files/directories are processed in [..delete] sections... You're welcome! Can accept the answer as well. ;)